# Using Double-Quotation Marks in a URL

Tags: php, html

The link below works fine unless the variable `$row["title"]` contains a double-quotation mark (").  In that case, everything after the quotation marks is omitted in the link.

How can I make the link include everything after a double-quotation mark?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www...com/.../comments/index.php?submission='.$row["title"].'">'.$row["countComments"].' COMMENTS</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Always use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) for parts of a URL which might need to contain anything unusual....

```
echo '<td class="sitename2">'.
  '<a href="http://www...com/.../comments/index.php?submission='.
  urlencode($row["title"]).
  '">'.
  $row["countComments"].' COMMENTS</a></td>';
```

If you want to get into the standards, refer to [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) which defines the safe, or 'unreserved' character as follows:

> unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

urlencode makes sure that a value you want to include in a URL obeys these standards

Comment: FWIW, the newer [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) says that only `-._~` are special (so you may also need to encode `!*'()`).

Comment: Thanks Carl, I've amended the answer to refer to the newer RFC

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you urlencode your URL parameter values. see [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode)

Answer (score 2):

```
. urlencode($row['title']) . '"> etc
```

Answer (score 2):

the values of parameters in a url must be escaped in order for the url to be valid.

so instead of

```
$row["title"]
```

use

```
urlencode($row["title"])
```

urlencode will transform the double-quote into **%22** so you will avoid the problem with the wrong double-quote ending your link.

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 1):

In my case, urlencode did not help, I used `urlencode ($var)` and the result in the browser is:
localhost/"aaMoldau+-+Aus+dem+Zyklus++"Mein+Vaterland""/

What the browser says:

An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

And here is my MYSQL entry ($var):

aaMoldau - Aus dem Zyklus  "Mein Vaterland"

update:

the quotes in the beginning and end of $var are clear, because I inserted them, but still the error is there.

(I do not understand why urlencode creates double quotes in the beginning and in the end.)

Furthermore, the double quote before 'Mein' and after Vaterland should be removed ?

Update 2:
I now used 
    `str_replace` to remove the double quotes together with urlencode and it is fine. But I thought I did not need str_replace ?

Furthermore, I read another post of stack where it is recommended to change my allowed uri chars to:
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=\a-z 0-9~%.:_-';

Here CodeIgnite was the problem but now solved. Strange that CI does not accept `+` in principal which is needed in spaces .